# How to find out where a function is called from in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, call

*Is it possible to find out where a function is called from?* If yes, then
how to detect, if a function is called from a **global scope**, from **another function**, or perhaps from a **browser console**?

Take a look at the following example:

```
<script>
    function myFunc1() {
        // some code
        myFunc2(); // I was called from myFunc1()
    }
    function myFunc2() {
        var callerName = new String;
        callerName = arguments.callee.caller.name;
        // some code
        alert('I was called from ' + callerName + ' function');
    }
    myFunc2(); // I was called from global scope
</script>
```

I know that this line `callerName = arguments.callee.caller.name;`in the example above, would give me *caller function's name.* But I don't know *how to detect if a function was called from a global scope.* For instance if I change `myFunc2()` and add an `if else` statement to check if `arguments.callee.caller.name` returns an `undefined` value, knowing that this will happen, when a function is called from a global scope:

```
myFunc2() {
var callerName = new String;
callerName = arguments.callee.caller.name;
    if(callerName == undefined) {
        alert('I was called from global scope');
    } else {
        alert('I was called from ' + callerName + ' function');
    }
}
```

However, this will not work if `myFunc2()` is called from a global scope and `callerName = arguments.callee.caller.name;` will cause JavaScript to throw the following error:

```
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'arguments.callee.caller.name')
```

So I am back to square one, and the question still remains:

- How to detect if a function is called from a **global scope?**
- If it's called from a global scope, is it from a **browser console?**

Comment: `x = arguments.callee.caller ? arguments.callee.caller.name : "global";` will fix your TypeError I think. `null.name` does not make sense, and will generate an error.

Comment: This works but could you explain how? What happens in this statement: `x = arguments.callee.caller ? arguments.callee.caller.name`

Comment: `?` is a binary operator. `x = arguments.callee.caller ? arguments.callee.caller.name : "global";` will evaluate `(boolean) arguments.callee.caller`. If this is true, then it will assign `arguments.callee.caller.name` to x. If it is false, then it will assign `"global"` to x. `(boolean) null` is `false`, preventing the code from trying to get it's name.

Comment: So `callerName = arguments.callee.caller ? arguments.callee.caller.name : "global";` is equal to:          `if(arguments.callee.caller) {
  callerName = arguments.callee.caller.name;
 } else {
  callerName = "global";
 }`

Comment: Yes, but a binary operator is in this case easier to read.

Comment: What do you mean by "where a function is called from"? You seem to be trying to get the name of the function that called your function. But not every function has a name JavaScript.

Answer (score 35):

In Chrome, you can use:

```
console.trace();
```

Just add that line in your function, I usually place it as the first line. If you view the console you'll see the name of your function, and below that line you'll see where it's being called from.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, simple and incredibly useful!

Comment: Simple answer but what if I want a string that holds the info from where the function was called so that I can print it or send it somewhere else? Simply console logging the path won't do it

Comment: how could this functionality exist and not be on the must know list of JS. Thank you for the enlightenment

Answer (score 8):

If the function is called from the global scope, `arguments.callee.caller.name` will be undefined. Otherwise, it will be the name of the caller function (which also represents the scope it was called from).

So what you already have should work, except in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode), where `arguments.callee` is not available.

---

Additionaly: the developer tools available from your browser are probably a better way to inspect this kind of thing: just set a breakpoint and look at the stack trace panel. Unless of course your code itself needs to know the calling scope at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your browser, you could provoke and error, by accessing an undefined variable for example, inside a `try/catch`. Then examine the stack trace some browsers provide in the error.

This will be very browser specific.

Comment: As a side note, that's basically how http://www.eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/ works

Comment: love the idea but "provoking" an error seems confusing,. why not just throwing one?

Comment: You don't have to you use `try/catch`. Simply `new Error().stack` will show the same information.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function func1() {
    // some code
    func2(); // I was called from func1()
}
function func2() {
var callerName = new String;
callerName = arguments.callee.caller ? arguments.callee.caller.name : "global";
    if(callerName == "global") {
        alert('I was called from global scope');
    } else {
        alert('I was called from ' + callerName + ' function');
    }
}
func1();
func2(); // I was called from global scope
```

func2 is called it will display its caller name, if it was called within another function scope, it will display that function's name and if it was called from global scope it will display a message that shows it was called from the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript most things are objects, when you declare `callerName = new String` you create a **string object** with some properties and methods. For instance, the `valueOf()` method will return the *primitive value of a string object.* However, just like JavaScript tells you `'TypeError: 'null' is not an object` **null is not an object** but rather, *it's the absence of an object.* **null doesn't have any methods or properties.** When a function is called from a global scope, `arguments.callee.caller` evaluates caller to **null.** So`arguments.callee.caller.name` is like trying to access **null's `name` property (`null.name`)**, but null *doesn't have a property called `name`,* since it's not an object and *can not* have any property at all. This is why JavaScript complains, because you are trying to ***access something that doesn't exist.*** What you can do however, is to first **check if `caller` is a falsy value** by using a simple `if else` statement `if(!arguments.callee.caller)`, *if it isn't,* then you can access the `name` property of the `caller` and find out what function has called `myFunc2()`, *but if it is*, then you know the function was called from a global scope.

```
function myFunc2() {
    if(!arguments.callee.caller) {
        callerName = "global";
        alert('I was called from global scope');
    } else {
        callerName = arguments.callee.caller.name;
        alert('I was called from ' + callerName + ' function');
    }
}
```

Comment: please  consider making the `callerName` local to the function because otherwise it will pollute the window.

Answer (score 1):

That's quite a tricky question. As discussed on this answer Arguments.callee is deprecated in some browsers.

Depending on your approach you can use Function.caller.
I have written a quite [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/m2n0s5r8/)

```
function A() {
    if (A.caller === null || A.caller.name == "") console.log("Function called from top window")
    else console.log("Called from " + A.caller.name);
    B();
}

function B() {
    if (B.caller === null || B.caller.name == "") console.log("Function called from top window")
    else console.log("Called from " + B.caller.name);
}

A();
```

Another more generic example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bladnman/EhUm3/)

Still `'use strict'` makes both these approaches fail, so using a `try / catch` block can solve your problem or you may simulate a "[dummy call stack](http://jsfiddle.net/m2n0s5r8/1/)" for your functions ( depending on the fact that all your code works synchronously  )

Answer (score 0):

You might just create an instance of Error & call its stack method inside the function to see the call stack

```
const stack = new Error().stack()
console.log(stack)
```

above two lines of code should be inside the function body, an example might be

```
function calculateAge() {
  const stack = new Error().stack();
  console.log(stack);
}
```